# Обработка повторного клика на пункт меню в методе onOptionsItemSelected()

Tags: android

Как обработать повторное нажатие на пункт меню в методе `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`?

Чтобы при первом нажатии на пункт меню выполнялось одно действие, а при втором и последующих-другое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавь счётчик за пределами функции вызываемой в ивеньте

`let counter = 0`

В функцию вызываемую при ивенте добавь проверку

`if (conter == 0){/*Первое событие*/} else{/*второе+ событие*/}`

После в этой же функции добавь

```
counter++
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Всё получилось!

Comment: Нажмите на галочку возле моего ответа, что бы вопрос не висел открытым.